# Read Android Contacts and Edit it and export it as vcf in Android using java

Tags: java, android, eclipse, contacts

Hi I am new in developing java application and I want to make application to edit phone numbers on contacts so I want to access android contacts and make backup and then edit its phone numbers .

I read some about it but not enough I put permissions in manifest file and

> imported android.provider.Contacts
>
> imported android.provider.ContactsContract;

but unfortunately I didn't know howa to read contacts from it as contact to export it as .vcf and edit in it ? So I need Help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link i was found to solve some of your problems.

[Import/Export of Android contacts in vCard format](http://code.google.com/p/vcardio/)